# TikZ crop image

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to crop everything outside the bounding box?

I made some periodic pattern in TikZ but I wanna crop it outside some box. Just making a bounding box helps for the alignment but the pattern still repeats outside the box.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simply use the `\clip` macro or `\path [clip]` and draw your bounding box, e.g. using `\clip (lower left coordinate) rectangle (upper right coordinate)`. You can access the bounding box of everything drawn so far using the `current bounding box` shape: `\clip (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);`. You need to do so before you apply the pattern, I think.
If you already use `\useasboundingbox` or the equivalent `\path [use as bounding box]` then you can simply add the `clip` option to it.

If you only want to clip some drawing commands place them with the `\clip` into a `scope` environment.